# Can I pass object of data in select option

Tags: reactjs

Can I pass object of data in select option ?

I'm displaying name in select option & I'm using ID in value.

After some option is selected, I want to display the selected option. Since the value is ID, I can't display name.

How can I solve this?

This is my code:

```
{
 Makes.hasData ?
   (_.map(Makes.data.data, (make, index) => {
       return (
             <option key={index} value={make.id}> {make.make}</option>
         );
     }))
    : ''
}
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your select option you will have onChange in that you can search in the array for the obejct with a given id using lodash's `find` method

```
handleChange(e) {
    var id=e.target.value
    var value = _.result(_.find(Makes.data.data, function(obj) {
         return obj.id=== id;
     }), 'make');
    console.log(value)
}
```